# I have a problem with InlineKeyboardButton in python telegram API

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

*This is what my bot will do:*
If someone sends a *command* like *\sendFriendReq* to my bot, then my bot will send a message with their details and an **Inline Button** with with **"yes"** and **"no"**.

*The problem I'm facing:* How can i know who send those messages other than formatting the text with their details, is there a way to send their chat id along with the inline button so i can use that chat id to send a reply to my bot users

**Disclaimer:** This is not the actual problem but the solution to this problem could solve my problem so alternate solution to send friend req won't help me

Comment: Sounds like a [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Anyway, please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to add a [*minimal*, *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

This would give you pretty much every detail about the incomming message:

```
userid = update.message.from_user.id
firstname = update.message.from_user.first_name
lastname = update.message.from_user.last_name
fullname = update.message.from_user.full_name
username = update.message.from_user.name
message = update.message.text
chatid = update.message.chat_id
```

Comment: This would give the details of last message but I will have many message with inline button so how would i know who sent these messages since my bot sends those messages, if i use these i will get my bots details.
what i need is somehow to send some data along with the inline button so i can use it in callback 

Any way I appreciate your answer tho its not what i'm looking for :)

Comment: I didn't really get what you mean. but I guess you wanna collect all those data.
In that case, you should use a database. Then use the above piece of code to collect user data, and add them to a database each time .

Comment: ok then just think like this, You started a conversation with a bot by clicking START button then the bot sends a Yes or No inline button to a specific person (lets say bot owner) ,if the owner clicks yes then the user (you) can continue conversations with bot.But the problem is there will be hundreds of users for my bot and when they click START i will have that many Yes or No inline button message which send by my bot to the specific person(owner), so when i click yes to a message then only the person who send that message should be allowed for conversation.